# Why this url generate 404 not found exception?

Tags: php, rest, slim

I need your help to understand this behavior.
I have defined this url in SlimFramework :

```
$app->get('/media', function () {
    echo "Test";
});
```

I have an error "404 not found exception" when i enter this url in my browser. If i change this url to anything else like :

```
$app->get('/test', function () {
    echo "Test";
});
```

This works and displays "Test" in my browser. Is the route /media is a reserve rule or something like this. All other routes works great so i think it is not a config mistake.

Comment: Maybe you have `media` folder  in your site's structure?

Comment: yes i have one , I have delete it, but same still 404.

Comment: Can you clean cache and retry?

Comment: how can i do this with slimFramework? I already clean firefox cache

Comment: This is a cache problem, but i can't resolve it. Another url get off because i create directory with the same name. Even after i delete it : 404 error. I use MAMP and i disable OPCache but same result.

Comment: Ok i re clean firefox cache and all works. I don't know why. But i'm ok. thx

Comment: Instead of cleaning the entire cache you could use an incognito tab or the developer tools of your browser have a option to ignore the cache (at least, that's the case with Chrome)